# How to get Integer input from Java Scanner

Tags: java, function, input

I have this code in java , the code works good

```
public class MaximumTest {
   // determines the largest of three Comparable objects
   public static <T extends Comparable<T>> T maximum(T x, T y, T z)
   {                      
      T max = x; // assume x is initially the largest       
      if ( y.compareTo( max ) > 0 ){
         max = y; // y is the largest so far
      }
      if ( z.compareTo( max ) > 0 ){
         max = z; // z is the largest now                 
      }
      return max; // returns the largest object   
   }
   public static void main( String args[] )
   {
      System.out.printf(maximum( 3, 4, 5 ) );
   }
}
```

but know I want to get input from the user instead of maximum( 3, 4, 5 ) so I did like this :

```
import java.util.Scanner;
 public class MammalInt {

     public static <T extends Comparable<T>> T maximum (T x, T y, T z){
     T max=x;
     if(y.compareTo(max)>0){
    max= y;
     }
     if (z.compareTo(max)>0){
         max=z;
     } return max;
     }
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner x=new Scanner(System.in);
        Scanner y=new Scanner(System.in);
        Scanner z=new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println(maximum(x,y,z));

    }
    }
```

unfortunately the code does not work , there is a problem in line : System.out.println(maximum(x,y,z));

eclipse says: Bound mismatch: The generic method maximum(T, T, T) of type MammalInt is not applicable for the arguments (Scanner, Scanner, Scanner). The inferred type Scanner is not a valid substitute for the bounded parameter 
 >

Do you have any solution for this problem ???

thanks

Comment: Please define "does not work" and "there is a problem". It looks like you're currently trying to compare scanners with each other. Why aren't you creating a single scanner, reading from it multiple times, e.g. with `Scanner.nextLine`) and then passing the results of those calls to your `maximum` method?

Comment: Hi brother , I got this from eclipse : Bound mismatch: The generic method maximum(T, T, T) of type MammalInt is not applicable for the arguments (Scanner, Scanner, Scanner). The inferred type Scanner is not a valid substitute for the bounded parameter 
 <T extends Comparable<T>>

Comment: So please put that into the question. Now, do you understand that there's a difference between a `Scanner` object and "data read from a `Scanner`"? How would you compare two `Scanner` objects with each other?

Comment: I did add the comment ..  Now, do you understand that there's a difference between a Scanner object and "data read from a Scanner"? So one Scanner object could be used to get different inputs ... How would you compare two Scanner objects with each other? may be by using compareTo()

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `Scanner` object is not the input. The `Scanner` provides you with a method `nextInt()` to request user input.

This is how your main method should look:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner sc =new Scanner(System.in);
    int x = sc.nextInt();
    int y = sc.nextInt();
    int z = sc.nextInt();

    System.out.println(maximum(x,y,z));

}
```

Comment: @bcsb1001: No, that's not what that question is talking about. It's fine to call `nextInt` three times.

Comment: @JonSkeet Yeah, got a bit confused there.

Answer (score 1):

Do:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.println(maximum(sc.nextInt(), sc.nextInt(), sc.nextInt()));
```

That way the method runs with the values of the input rather than the `Scanner` itself.

Answer (score 0):

Considering the fact you  did not post any error message, only the code. I would try this as a possibility to correct your error.
May be you can try this :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner s=new Scanner(System.in);
         int x = s.nextInt();
         int y = s.nextInt();
         int z = s.nextInt();
        System.out.println(maximum(x,y,z));

    }
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing, but I am really not sure that this is required by the OP. The error is still unknown.

Comment: That is the only error in this code (this fix runs for me).

Comment: well I am glad then! Thanks though.